# how do I use my motorala blur 3-G or internet full time when I not a wi-fi spot?

Tags: wifi-tethering

I have a wi-fi connection at home. can get on internet, facebook and everything else, with my wi-fi connection. How do I use my motorola blur, that has 3-G full time?

Answer (score 1):

Android devices' inherent behaviour is to opt for a WiFi connection over mobile EDGE / 3G / 4G data. In order to force a device to use the mobile data connection instead of the WiFi, just turn off the WiFi.

There are a number of apps like Llama / Locale / Tasker that can automatically enable/disable your WiFi connection depending on your location and other user-specified conditions.